# WebForms ListBox - adding an item doesn't work if ListBox contains item already

Tags: c#, vb.net, webforms

I have a listbox:

```
<asp:ListBox runat="server" ID ="lbxIncidentsSel" Rows="4" SelectionMode="Single"></asp:ListBox>
```

And some code triggered by a button click to add some items:

```
Protected Sub btnIncidentsAdd_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    Dim lbxIncidentsSel As ListBox = CType(NormalFormView.FindControl("lbxIncidentsSel"), ListBox)        
    ' logic here is unimportant
    lbxIncidentsSel.Items.Add(SomeItem) ' this can be a list of items
    lbxIncidentsSel.DataBind()
End Sub
```

For the first item(s) I try to add, the item(s) will add fine, and display on the `lbxIncidentsSel` ListBox on the page.

The next item(s) I try to add, the item(s) will add in the code-behind correctly, I can see them in the `Items` drilldown but then on page rendering they **DO NOT DISPLAY**.

If I try to re-add the same items or others, in the code-behind that 2nd lot is no longer in the list and the whole process repeats - it will add it on the code-behind correctly but doesn't add on the display.

**Why does this work for the first item (or set of items) I add but not any others?**

Please note the code is in vb.net but the problem occurs in c# codebehind too

Comment: Try it without the `DataBind()` call.

Comment: It was initially without the DataBind and I only put that in to try and fix it. I had to resort to clearing all the items from the list and reinstating them plus the new ones. Only way I could get it to work.

Comment: OK, it was worth a thought. I just noticed something, though. You're declaring the variable `lbxIncidentsSel` with the same name as you've given the control. That likely has something to do with it (haven't tested). Why are you using the `FindControl` construct anyway? Just refer to the `ListBox` control directly in your code as you would any other. Comment out the variable declaration line and run it. It should work as you expect.

Comment: Because it's a horrible webform page with different views that can be active at any time, that means the `lbxIncidentsSel` isn't always available to the code-behind, depending on which view is active, so I can't directly refer to it otherwise the page load simply errors out whenever the right view isn't active.

Comment: I don't know why it's been set up like this - it breaks HTML rules because different views for the same data model will have the same ID - that means there'll be the same ID on your HTML pages (before rendering) so if you copy and paste a snippet the ID automatically changes because VS thinks it's doing you a favour by removing duplicate ID's, pain in the rectum.

Comment: On a whim, I built an SPA WebForms app like that some years ago. At first I thought I was being clever, but I ended up regretting it in the long run. It turned out to be a maintenance and debugging nightmare. I suspect the problem has something to do with the interruption of the natural ASP.NET page cycle by this architecture. If I remember correctly, I ended up doing a lot of stuff in `Page_Load`, under the `IsPostBack` property.

Comment: Yeah I bet it seemed like a good idea at the time, it was probably a good innovative way by MS to save some time back then, but since I'm relatively new to web development and inherited a web app with 40 pages like this... some of them 2000+ lines of html,compared to the asp net core stuff I actually started with some of the WebForms stuff really boggles my mind. It has some nice features but overall I can't wait to replace it!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221325/discussion-between-intexx-and-jamheadart).

Answer (score 1):

I solved this by recording the items that existed in the `ListBox` in a separate list, then clearing the actual `ListBox` before adding the recorded list AND the new entries.

I have no idea why this is necessary, it seems strange behaviour but there we go.